# cut/edit row lines and then transpose rows to column arrays

Tags: arrays, unix, awk, sed, grep

I've greatly simplified the values in the question

I have 500k lines of text in a space-delim file that I need to extract `x`, `y` values for plotting from each row and transpose those rows to columns. I'm trying to determine the most efficient way of doing this, and I've most been working in a bash script using `sed` and `awk` -- but if there are better ways of doing this, I'm open to suggestions.

The following code block is a simple example of the first 3 lines of text. The first 4 values (a,b,c,num) can be ignored but then each pair of values (separated by 0.000) needs to be cut and placed into a column and I need to do this for every line. The **2, 3 or 2** (right after `c`) tells us how many x,y pairs follow in the line, starting with `2500` and `500`

Sample input:

```
a   b   c   2   2500.0  500.0   0.000   0.0 10.0            
a   b   c   3   2000.0  450.0   0.000   1000.0  400.0   0.000   0.0 12.0
a   b   c   2   1800.0  475.0   0.000   0.0 15.0
```

Expected output:

```
2500.0  500.0   2000.0  450.0   1800.0  475.0
0.0     10.0    1000.0  400.0   0.0     15.0
                0.0     12.0
```

Comment: correct, yes my mistake

Comment: You didn't specify a language for "array of arrays". Bash doesn't haven multi dimensional arrays, but there are ways of getting that level of indirection. You can also use pseudo 2D arrays in awk, or real 2D arrays in gawk.

Comment: I edited your question to show what I now think you want as sample input and expected output. If I guessed wrong please feel free to roll the question back and then correct it to show the real sample input and expected output you want.

Comment: this (below) doesn't seem bash friendly?

Answer (score 0):

I had a flash of inspiration - is this what you're trying to do:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { OFS="\t" }
{
    rowNr = 0
    for ( i=6; i<NF; i+=3 ) {
        val = $i OFS $(i+1)
        vals[++rowNr,NR] = val
    }
    numRows = ( rowNr > numRows ? rowNr : numRows )
}
END {
    numCols = NR
    for ( rowNr=1; rowNr<=numRows; rowNr++ ) {
        for ( colNr=1; colNr<=numCols; colNr++ ) {
            val = ( (rowNr,colNr) in vals ? vals[rowNr,colNr] : OFS )
            printf "%s%s", val, (colNr<numCols ? OFS : ORS)
        }
    }
}
```

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file
2500.0  500.0   2000.0  450.0   1800.0  475.0
0.0     10.0    1000.0  400.0   0.0     15.0
                0.0     12.0
```

---

Previous answers:

Using your new example:

```
$ awk '{for (i=6;i<NF;i+=3) print $i, $(i+1)}' file
2500.0 500.0
0.0 10.0
2000.0 450.0
1000.0 400.0
0.0 12.0
1800.0 475.0
0.0 15.0
```

Original answer:

```
$ awk '{for (i=5;i<NF;i+=3) print $i, $(i+1)}' file
2328.948975 287.601868
2091.017578 168.763153
1949.201782 38.351677
1926.619385 43.498230
1808.323120 91.477585
1792.807861 60.784626
1650.532471 25.608397
1630.271484 54.119873
1615.212891 4.026413
1502.170288 118.276688
1176.283447 43.057251
1119.772705 56.983471
944.500000 81.461624
937.491516 107.800484
726.215515 181.033768
641.585510 82.066551
443.907104 27.303604
362.327789 90.082993
348.752777 39.833252
61.434803 44.582367
0.000000 7.181455
```

Comment: this does extract the FIRST LINE correctly...however it is then repeated, which is not what I want. I want to go through the file that has 500,000 lines and print each line (just like the one above) with a varying number of pairs in each line...to an array

Comment: If this doesn't answer your question, you need to explain it better. How are proceeding lines different to your example line? It's a good answer based on the information you have provided.

Comment: the proceeding lines are different in that they are slightly different values and or number of records across the 500,000 lines. I can't put them all on here.

Comment: I've edited the question to show more than one line...this goes on for 500,000 lines. The above answer crudely does *exactly* what I mentioned but for only one line, although that action also also prints that same output repeatedly. Perhaps something like this in a loop?

Comment: I can't see anything in your question to make me think the script I posted wouldn't work as-is. Assuming it doesn't, please edit your question to provide briefer and clearer sample input AND the expected output given that input. As for printing "to an array" - I don't know what that means.

Comment: Do you mean you want to populate an awk array or a bash array? No matter which, how should it be populated - with these pairs of values as indices or values with incrementing indices or some other kind of indices, or a mapping of 1 to the other or something else? Again, please edit your question to clarify what you're trying to do.

Comment: Regarding [however it is then repeated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71341882/cut-edit-row-lines-and-then-transpose-rows-to-array-of-arrays#comment126104191_71342581) and [although that action also also prints that same output repeatedly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71341882/cut-edit-row-lines-and-then-transpose-rows-to-array-of-arrays#comment126105470_71342581) - again, I don't know what you mean by that, there's nothing in my script that will repeat anything, it simply transposes each row into columns as you asked for,

Comment: You're doing something wrong as my script does exactly what you appear to be saying you want and prints all of the pairs for every line in the input. I don't know what you're doing wrong as I can't see your code and I can't demonstrate that my script does what you want because the multi-line example in your question has too many fields per line to make displaying the output sensible and you haven't provided the expected output to compare it to anyway. Please just do what I asked in my comment and post input like `a b c d e f g h i` and `k l m n o p q` and show the expected output.

Comment: I want to do what your answer does *on each line in the file* and then save the output as columns (everything is currently in rows). Currently, it is writing stacked columns in the text file, which are not useful since the number of x-y points intermittently changes for each row. I need each x-y pair to be in their own columns

Comment: Again - it does what you want best i can tell without seeing your expected output for some multi-line input. If what I'm doing isn't want you want then simply show us what you want. idk what else to say.